# Defining a stack data structure and its main operations in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, combinators, y-combinator

I'm trying to define a `stack` data structure in lambda calculus, using fixed point combinators. I am trying to define two operations, `insertion` and `removal` of elements, so, `push` and `pop`, but the only one I've been able to define, the insertion, is not working properly. The removal I could not figure out how to define.

This is my approach on the `push` operation, and my definition of a `stack`:

```
Stack definition:
STACK = \y.\x.(x y)
PUSH = \s.\e.(s e)
```

My stacks are initialize with an element to indicate the bottom; I'm using a `0` here:

```
stack = STACK 0 = \y.\x.(x y) 0 = \x.(x 0)       // Initialization
stack = PUSH stack 1 = \s.\e.(s e) stack 1 =     // Insertion
    = \e.(stack e) 1 = stack 1 = \x.(x 0) 1 =
    = (1 0)
```

But now, when I try to insert another element, it does not work, as my initial structure has be deconstructed.

How do I fix the `STACK` definition or the `PUSH` definition, and how do I define the `POP` operation? I guess I'll have to apply a combinator, to allow recursion, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic

Any further explanation or example on the definition of a data structure in lambda calculus will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't a singly linked a perfect stack with `push` = `cons` and `pop` = `head/tail`? I'm bringing this up because singly linked lists have been done a thousand times already, and may be easier to think about.

Comment: @delnan This is close to the approach I've proposed in my answer, as I've used part of the `list` definition to define the `stack`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stack in the lambda calculus is just a singly linked list. And a singly linked list comes in two forms:

```
nil  = λz. λf. z
cons = λh. λt. λz. λf. f h (t z f)
```

This is [Church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), with a list represented as its [catamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism). Importantly, you do not need a fixed point combinator at all. In this view, a stack (or a list) is a function taking one argument for the `nil` case and one argument for the `cons` case. For example, the list `[a,b,c]` is represented like this:

```
cons a (cons b (cons c nil))
```

The empty stack `nil` is equivalent to the `K` combinator of the SKI calculus. The `cons` constructor is your `push` operation. Given a head element `h` and another stack `t` for the tail, the result is a new stack with the element `h` at the front.

The `pop` operation simply takes the list apart into its head and tail. You can do this with a pair of functions:

```
head = λs. λe. s e (λh. λr. h)
tail = λs. λe. s e (λh. λr. r nil cons)
```

Where `e` is something that handles the empty stack, since popping the empty stack is undefined. These can be easily turned into one function that returns the pair of `head` and `tail`:

```
pop = λs. λe. s e (λh. λr. λf. f h (r nil cons))
```

Again, the pair is Church encoded. A pair is just a higher-order function. The pair `(a, b)` is represented as the higher order function `λf. f a b`. It's just a function that, given another function `f`, applies `f` to both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; this approach is way much closer to what I'm used to see in sml. Considering my approach, it may not be necessary, as you've pointed, but using a fixed point combinator I've reached something that really seemed to work. Is it wrong somehow? Or simply not the standard? And, if it isn't wrong, would you mind to take a look at the application I pointed in the bounty message? Regards!

Comment: I don't think your `Y` implementation is wrong in any way, it's just needlessly complicated. The `Y` combinator is strictly more powerful than you need, as it allows you to construct unbounded (infinite) stacks.

Comment: Ah, that's the confirmation I've been looking for! Thanks very much for the patience, and I totally agree that the way I did write the functions got even confusing. I'll wait for any further comments until the end of the bounty to reward the post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

By defining a combinator, which:

> is defined as a lambda term with no free variables, so by definition any combinator is already a lambda term,

you can define, for example, a list structure, by writing:

```
Y = (list definition in lambda calculus)
Y LIST = (list definition in lambda calculus) LIST
Y LIST = (element insertion definition in lambda calculus)
```

Intuitively, and using a fixed point combinator, a possible definition is -- consider \ = lambda:

- a list is either empty, followed by a trailing element, say `0`;
- or a list is formed by an element `x`, that may be another list inside the former one.

Since it's been defined with a combinator -- fixed point combinator --, there's no need to perform further applications, the following abstraction is a lambda term itself.

```
Y = \f.\y.\x.f (x y)
```

Now, naming it a LIST:

```
Y LIST = (*\f*.\y.\x.*f* (x y)) *LIST* -- applying function name
LIST = \y.\x.LIST (x y), and adding the trailing element "0"
LIST = (\y.\x.LIST (x y) ) 0
LIST = (*\y*.\x.LIST (x *y*) ) *0*
LIST = \x.LIST (x 0), which defines the element insertion abstraction.
```

The fixed point combinator `Y`, or simply combinator, allows you to consider the definition of LIST already a valid member, with no free variables, so, with no need for reductions.

Then, you can append/insert elements, say 1 and 2, by doing:

```
LIST = (\x.LIST (x 0)) 1 2 =
    = (*\x*.LIST (*x* 0)) *1* 2 =
    = (LIST (1 0)) 2 =
```

But here, we know the definition of list, so we expand it:

```
    = (LIST (1 0)) 2 =
    = ((\y.\x.LIST (x y)) (1 0)) 2 =
    = ((*\y*.\x.LIST (x *y*)) *(1 0)*) 2 =
    = ( \x.LIST (x (1 0)) ) 2 =
```

Now, inserting elemenet `2`:

```
    = ( \x.LIST (x (1 0)) ) 2 =
    = ( *\x*.LIST (*x* (1 0)) ) *2* =
    = LIST (2 (1 0))
```

Which can both be expanded, in case of a new insertion, or simply left as is, due to the fact that LIST is a lambda term, defined with a combinator.

Expanding for future insertions:

```
    = LIST (2 (1 0)) =
    = (\y.\x.LIST (x y)) (2 (1 0)) =
    = (*\y*.\x.LIST (x *y*)) *(2 (1 0))* =
    = \x.LIST (x (2 (1 0))) =
    = ( \x.LIST (x (2 (1 0))) ) (new elements...)
```

I'm really glad I've been able to derive this myself, but I'm quite sure there must be some good bunch of extra conditions, when defining a stack, a heap, or some fancier structure.

Trying to derive the abstraction for a stack insertion/removal -- without all the step-by-step:

```
Y = \f.\y.\x.f (x y)
Y STACK 0 = \x.STACK (x 0)
STACK = \x.STACK (x 0)
```

To perform the operation upon it, let's name an empty stack -- allocating a variable (:

```
stack = \x.STACK (x 0)

// Insertion -- PUSH STACK VALUE -> STACK
PUSH = \s.\v.(s v)
stack = PUSH stack 1 =
    = ( \s.\v.(s v) ) stack 1 =
    = ( \v.(stack v) ) 1 =
    = ( stack 1 ) = we already know the steps from here, which will give us:
    = \x.STACK (x (1 0))

stack = PUSH stack 2 =
    = ( \s.\v.(s v) ) stack 2 =
    = ( stack 2 ) =
    = \x.STACK x (2 (1 0))

stack = PUSH stack 3 =
    = ( \s.\v.(s v) ) stack 3 =
    = ( stack 3 ) =
    = \x.STACK x (3 (2 (1 0)))
```

And we, once again, name this result, for us to pop the elements:

```
stack = \x.STACK x (3 (2 (1 0)))

// Removal -- POP STACK -> STACK
POP = \s.(\y.s (y (\t.\b.b)))
stack = POP stack =
    = ( \s.(\y.s y (\t.\b.b)) ) stack =
    = \y.(stack (y (\t.\b.b))) = but we know the exact expansion of "stack", so:
    = \y.((\x.STACK x (3 (2 (1 0))) ) (y (\t.\b.b))) =
    = \y.STACK y (\t.\b.b) (3 (2 (1 0))) = no problem if we rename y to x (:
    = \x.STACK x (\t.\b.b) (3 (2 (1 0))) =
    = \x.STACK x (\t.\b.b) (3 (2 (1 0))) = someone guide me here, if i'm wrong
    = \x.STACK x (\b.b) (2 (1 0)) =
    = \x.STACK x (2) (1 0) =
    = \x.STACK x (2 (1 0))
```

For what, hopefully, we have the element `3` popped.

I've tried to derive this myself, so, if there's any restriction from lambda calculus I didn't followed, please, point it out.

Comment: similarly how can we define stack and queue ??

Comment: @AnupamTamrakar I've added the `stack` insertion/removal; check it out. Regards!